# Transcendental extensions of $\mathbb{R}$ that are not purely transcendental

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, transcendence-theory

Purely transcendental extensions of $\mathbb{R}$ are those of the form $\mathbb{R}((X_i)_{i \in I})$ where $I$ is a set and the $X_i$'s are (distinct) indeterminates.

Now, I wonder if there is a transcendental extension of $\mathbb{R}$ that is not purely transcendental.

If such extensions exist, I wonder if there is a classical way to classify them in different categories.

Comment: What about $\Bbb C(X)$?

Comment: @Stahl : Thank you. Can you answer my second question ?

Comment: Note that algebraic closure or $\mathbb{R}$ is $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Instead of reals, if you work with complex numbers, this is birational classification of ALL complex algebraic varieties, in the case of finite transcendence degrees. Highly complicated problem and unresolved in any satisfactory manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $K/\Bbb R$ is a field extension, you can always find a transcendence basis $S$; i.e., a set $S\subseteq K$ such that $K$ is algebraic over $\Bbb R(S)$. The extension is purely algebraic if there exists a subset $S\subseteq K$ which is algebraically independent over $\Bbb{R}$ and $K = \Bbb R(S)$. So you're asking for a classification of algebraic extensions of $\Bbb R((X_i)_{i\in I})$. As I mentioned in the comments, $\Bbb C(X)$ is such an extension, but so is something like $\Bbb R(X^{1/p^\infty}) := \Bbb R(X,X^{1/p},X^{1/p^2},X^{1/p^3},\dots).$ As you can see, even in one variable the extensions can be quite complicated.

The answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/136233/to-what-extent-can-fields-be-classified) discusses the classification of fields in general, and what subjects are involved in trying to obtain such a classification.

Comment: $\mathbb R(X,\sqrt X)=\mathbb R(\sqrt X)$ *is* a purely transcendental extension of $\mathbb R$. For that matter, your claim that $K/\mathbb R$ is a purely transcendental extension if *and only if* $K=\mathbb R(S)$ is false.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Thanks for the corrections -- I was definitely too hasty when I answered this!